# iOS simulator cant connect to local network IP address

Tags: ios, ip, localhost, ios-simulator

To start, I used to be able to access locally hosted files on my simulator app with no problem.

After updating to OS X Yosemite, I can't connect to addresses like `http://192.168.2.6:8000` on my iOS simulator, that work fine in Chrome, or from my actual phone.

Is there a new setting I need to enable for local testing? Or are there any other potential issues for me to look at?

The error I get on safari (on iOS simulator) is:

`The error was: "The operation couldn't be completed. No such file or directory".`

And looking in the system.log I see this:

```
Oct 13 16:40:46 My-MacBook-Pro MobileSafari[4215]: tcp_connection_set_tfo 89 TFO is not yet supported on Simulator
```

Comment: Same issue here, after updating to OS X El Capitan, can't connect to my local IP (`192.168.5.x`) with iOS9 simulator (but i can connect `127.0.0.1`). iOS 8.4 simulator also works fine for both ips.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 seems to be a workaround on el capitan since the next update.

Comment: Would this have something to do with the App Transport Security HTTPS requirements perhaps? Or at least its implementation in the simulator. Have you tried [making a blanket ATS exception](http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/), and trying again?

Comment: A good summary of what TFO (TCP Fast Open, gotta love nested acronyms) is and how it works can be found here https://bradleyf.id.au/nix/shaving-your-rtt-wth-tfo/, though it's unclear whether the bug is really connected.

Comment: Is there any update to this issue? I am having the same and don't have any idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

This problem solved completely with iOS 9.2 and Xcode 7.2 :
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/RN-Xcode-Archive/Chapters/xc7_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016994-CH5-SW2

However, based on official releases notes of Xcode 7.2, it is still known issue for previous iOS versions (I checked it for iOS 8.2, but there is no problem anymore). You could use your loopback address (127.0.0.1 or localhost) for older versions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue that I believe was mentioned in the Xcode release notes.  Unfortunately, the only workaround at this time is to user the loopback interface (ie: 127.0.0.1) for your testing needs.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like a warning that http is going to be frowned on.
eg:

in UIWebView you cannot open, by default, an http// web-page

if you then open an https// web-page it opens but any images,etc. in it that refer to http// websites fail to load

I've just dealt with all that stuff, it certainly happens with the latest mac OS and the latest Xcode

Phil